# Rows Getting duplicated while doing summation

Tags: sql, join, sum

I have 3 tables. The join between first two tables in CONTR_ID and between second and third table is ENC_RCPT_ID.

**CONTR**

```
+----+----------+------+-----------+
| ID | CONTR_ID | CURR | TOT_CONTR |
+----+----------+------+-----------+
| 1  | 1        | USD  | 100       |
+----+----------+------+-----------+
| 2  | 2        | USD  | 80        |
+----+----------+------+-----------+
```

**INS_RCPT**

```
+----+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| ID | CONTR_ID | ENC_RCPT_ID | RCPT_CURR | RCPT_AMT |
+----+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 1  | 1        | 1           | USD       | 20       |
+----+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 2  | 1        | 2           | USD       | 30       |
+----+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 3  | 1        | 3           | USD       | 50       |
+----+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 4  | 2        | 4           | USD       | 60       |
+----+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 5  | 2        | 5           | USD       | 20       |
+----+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

**ENC_RCPT**

```
+----+-------------+--------------+
| ID | ENC_RCPT_ID | ENC_RCPT_AMT |
+----+-------------+--------------+
| 1  | 1           | 5            |
+----+-------------+--------------+
| 2  | 1           | 15           |
+----+-------------+--------------+
| 3  | 2           | 5            |
+----+-------------+--------------+
| 4  | 2           | 10           |
+----+-------------+--------------+
| 5  | 2           | 15           |
+----+-------------+--------------+
```

I want to show output as below:

```
+----------+------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| CONTR_ID | CURR | TOT_CONTR | RCPT_AMT | ENC_RCPT_AMT |
+----------+------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 1        | USD  | 100       | 100      | 50           |
+----------+------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 2        | USD  | 80        | 80       | 0            |
+----------+------+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

I have written below select query but it does not give correct result.

```
SELECT C.contr_id, C.curr, C.tot_contr, IR.rcpt_amt, ER.enc_rcpt_amt 
FROM   @CONTR AS C 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT contr_id, 
                               enc_rcpt_id, 
                               Sum(rcpt_amt) AS RCPT_AMT 
                        FROM   @INS_RCPT 
                        GROUP  BY contr_id, 
                                  enc_rcpt_id) AS IR 
                    ON IR.contr_id = C.contr_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ER1.enc_rcpt_id, 
                               Sum(ER1.enc_rcpt_amt) AS ENC_RCPT_AMT 
                        FROM   @ENC_RCPT AS ER1 
                               INNER JOIN @INS_RCPT AS IR1 
                                       ON IR1.enc_rcpt_id = ER1.enc_rcpt_id 
                        GROUP  BY ER1.enc_rcpt_id) AS ER 
                    ON ER.enc_rcpt_id = IR.enc_rcpt_id
```

Comment: please show us your output.

Comment: This involves a common error where people want some joins, each possibly involving a different key, of some subqueries, each possibly involving join and/or aggregation, but they erroneously try to do all the joining then all the aggregating or to aggregate over previous aggregations. Write separate aggregations over appropriate rows and/or aggregate a case statement picking rows; join on a unique column set. Sometimes DISTINCT aggregation picks the right values after a non-key join. (A join on a non-key of either of 2 input tables can give multiple rows for each key of each table.)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to force everything to be at the same grain, so you have to roll it all the way up.

```
SELECT C.contr_id, C.curr, C.tot_contr, r.rcpt_amt, r.enc_rcpt_amt
from
contr c 
left outer join (select
contr_id,
sum(rcpt_amt) as rcpt_amt,
sum(enc_rcpt_amt) as enc_rcpt_amt
from

(SELECT contr_id, 
                               enc_rcpt_id, 
                               Sum(rcpt_amt) AS RCPT_AMT 
                        FROM   INS_RCPT 
                        GROUP  BY contr_id, 
                                  enc_rcpt_id) AS IR 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ER1.enc_rcpt_id, 
                               Sum(ER1.enc_rcpt_amt) AS ENC_RCPT_AMT 
                        FROM   ENC_RCPT AS ER1 
                               INNER JOIN INS_RCPT AS IR1 
                                       ON IR1.enc_rcpt_id = ER1.enc_rcpt_id 
                        GROUP  BY ER1.enc_rcpt_id) AS ER 
                    ON ER.enc_rcpt_id = IR.enc_rcpt_id 
  group by
  contr_id) r 
  on c.contr_id = r.contr_id
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. That was wonderful. You made my day.

Answer (score 0):

An approach uses a couple of subqueries:

```
select
    c.*,
    (
        select sum(i.rcpt_amt) rcpt_amt)
        from ins_rcpt i 
        where i.contr_id = c.contr_id
    ) rcpt_amt,
    (
        select coalesce(sum(r.enc_crpt_amt), 0)
        from enc_rpct r
        where exists (
            select 1 
            from ins_rcpt i
            where i.contr_id = c.contr_id and i.enc_rcpt_id = r.enc_rcpt_id 
        )           
    ) enc_crpt_amt
from contr c
```